# Excel replace formula with value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

There are two columns A & B:

- A has formulas that extract values from another sheet.
- B is to input values.

If the input value in B is "Y", then the formula in A should get replaced with its static value obtained from formula. If B is empty A keeps its formula.

How can I achieve this for all rows?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, this can be done with the [`Worksheet_Change` Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel). This event occurs when a cell (`Target`) is changed.

So you just need to check if the `Target.Column` is the second column and if its value is `Y` and then move one column left `Target.Offset(0, -1)` and replace the value.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Value = "Y" Then
        Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that the input value `Y` is case sensitive and only works for upper case `Y`. To make it non case sensitive use `UCase(Target.Value) = "Y"` instead to accept lower case `y` as well.

Comment: Thank you, if instead of a cell I want that to happen for the whole row then?

Comment: what do you mean by "*whole row*" you need to be more precise.